# create a richtext uitableviewcell with uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

Well basically I am trying to pass a string to a uiwebview that just so happens to be in html format, however I am passing it to the uiwebview using **loadHTMLString:myHTML**.

the problem that I am having is that I cannot see any text at all. I have set up a custom view which I have then deleted the view, added a uitableviewcell then inside the cell I have added a uiwebview. I have then set the related class to the class in which I would like to display the tableviewcell, then linked my getter/setter to the tableviewcell and the uiwebview inside the tableviewcell..

Then this is the code that follows with me trying to set the richtext of the uiwebview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {


            // Set cell height
            [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            // Configure the cell using custom cell
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCellHtml" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = searchCellHtml;

            // pass in some data into myHTML
            myUIWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

            NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
            [myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];

            //Disclosure Indicator
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            // load the cell ?
            cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchCellHtml" owner:self options:nil];

            myUIWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] init] autorelease]; // autorelease


            NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
            [myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];

            //add webView to your cell
            myUIWebView.frame = cell.bounds;
            [cell addSubview:myUIWebView];

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
```

Comment: that worked thanks.. I only made two changes to your code, first I removed autorelease as I am using ARC. Then secondly I loaded the cell abit differentsly **[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AutomotiveSearchCellHtml" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = automativeSearchCellHtml;** like that.